# Federated GraphQL gateway update services and schema

Tags: kubernetes, graphql, apollo, federated

Take a scenario with a federated graphQL with multiple services where there are some services that depends on the others, like this:

[image]

The gateway was defined using Apollo:

```
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
  serviceList: services
});
```

Where services is an array of available running services.

There is a kubernetes managing the availability of each service, so every time a service goes up or goes down kubernetes warns the gateway so it update this array and with `gateway.load()` it updates the server with the correct available  services.

The problem is when a service goes down and some other service depends on it, like on the previous picture if **Role** goes down, **Person** is also affected.

I would like to know if it's possible to configure the gateway to change the schema of a service in order to take the dependency out. In this case when **Role** goes down, change **Person** schema so the client is not able to use this field anymore (since it is down).

If it is not possible, is there a work around solution?